# MySQL error starting

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I can't start mysql and when I run any type of start command, whether it be `systemctl start mysql` or `service mysql start`, I get the same error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And when I run `systemctl status mysql.service` I get this: https://hatebin.com/iefidgteub

Or if I run `mysql` I get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` so I looked around, and I ran `find / -type s` to try and locate the `mysqld.sock` file but in the output, `mysqld.sock` wasn't one of the files it returned

Then, if I try running `mysqld`, I get https://hatebin.com/nyszqpalec

Comment: How did you install MySQL?

Comment: It seems clear from your screen capture that `/var/lib/mysql-files` does not exist and does not contain the mysql files.  In many cases the default location is `/var/lib/mysql`.  Check whether they are already there, or do a `find` for `ibdata1`.  If they already exist somewhere else, set the path in `/etc/my.cnf` using `datadir=/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql` does exist, but in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`, `datadir=` is already set to `/var/lib/mysql` and in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/my.cnf` it's set to the same thing, though I did find out that in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` one of the `!includedir` was set to `/etc/mysql/conf.d` instead of `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` where all of those configuration files are, so I updated it and tried to start mysql but I still get the same error

Comment: Config is either being ignored or set to `/var/lib/mysql-files` somewhere.  If you want a practical fix and don't mind a hack, `mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-files`.  Otherwise you need to sort through the config files that are being read.

Comment: I did that, but still get the same error, what about the `mysqld.sock` file? Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Still getting these errors: https://hatebin.com/hzwjoidukt https://hatebin.com/ogvmgozhnq Though when I run `mysqld` it doesn't output an error

Comment: You have two different errors.  First is starting mysql.  Check that is running, e.g. `systemctl status mysql`, `ps -ef | grep mysql`.  Second error is related to the socket.  Check directory `/var/run/mysqld` exists and has correct ownership/permissions, and that mysqld is not trying to create the socket somewhere else.  As a higher level comment your mysql seems hosed.  Unless you actually have some data/settings worth keeping, I'd remove the lot and reinstall using a package manager.

Comment: https://hatebin.com/rbrmkypchd is the output of `systemctl status mysql` and the `/var/run/mysqld` directory doesn't exist

Comment: Also, reinstalling would be a bit of a pain considering I use Pterodactyl Panel, so I'd have to go through and set everything up again with the same credentials. So I hope there's another alternative

Comment: Look in `mysqld.log` for further errors.  If your configuration is hosed and you don't want to reinstall mysql, you will need to track down and fix each error one by one.  Regarding the socket, you'll need to either create `/var/run/mysqld` with appropriate ownership and permissions, or set `socket=` option in your mysql config.

Comment: Ok, for the socket issue, do I just create the `mysqld` folder? And then chmod with 777 permissions? And then when I start mysql after fixing other issues will it create the files by itself?

Comment: I ran `find / -iname mysqld.log` (I don't know if that's the right command to find the `mysqld.log` file) and it returned nothing, then I ran `locate -i mysqld` and it didn't return a log file

Comment: When creating the `/var/run/mysqld` folder, whenever I assign permissions the folder just deletes itself

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the log that you posted:

```
mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
2020-08-03T11:17:14.960692Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
```

Ensure the directory `/var/lib/mysql-files` exists and MySQL should start.

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql-files` doesn't exist, though `/var/lib/mysql` does

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of   ls   from the OS command prompt when in /var/lib/mysql ?

Comment: Sure, I changed it to `mysql-files` as I was asked to in a comment above, here's the output: https://hatebin.com/hjocqqtlne

Comment: Your prompt was - root@ubuntu:/var/lib/mysql-files# when you requested the ls.
Could you get to a prompt of /var/lib/mysql and request ls?  Then post the results, please.   I suspect mysql-files is an accidental folder that was created in the past.  We do not normally see a folder named mysql-files in a typical install.